# Change CSS of Dynamic buttons

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the follow and is able to do the alert. How can I change the class of the button selected?

```
$('body').on("click", "button[name=likebtn]", function (){
    alert($(this).attr("value"));

    $(this).toggleClass('btn btn-mini likebtn');
// OR

    $(this).addClass('btn btn-mini likebtn').removeClass('btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn');
});
```

The buttons are dynamically output:

```
$('#div').append("<button class='btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn' name='likebtn' type='button' value='"+obj.value+"'>"+"LIKE"+"</button>");
```

I tried the following but failed:

Comment: Is that inside a function or event or something? Can you please post all the code together as you have it?

Comment: sry, but I don't know why you will add and remove folowing classes 'btn btn-mini likebtn'. I thing that you will add and remove only 'btn-primary' class. $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `removeClass()` before `addClass()`

```
$(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn btn-mini likebtn');
```

Because you add `btn btn-mini likebtn` by `.addClass('btn btn-mini likebtn')` and then you remove them by calling `.removeClass('btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn');`

**EDIT**: If you want to remove `btn-primary` class only:

```
$('button[name=likebtn]').on("click", function (){
// ...
 $(this).removeClass('btn-primary');
});
```

Comment: This is not working... Where could go wrong? The button doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

if you add buttons to the body you have to run below code again

```
$('body').on("click", "button[name=likebtn]", function (){
    alert($(this).attr("value"));

    $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');

});
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain your solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of problem you have. :) But I thing that you will add adn remove just 'btn-primary' class, because all rest classes are still the same and I don't see any reason why add classes and remove them.

Comment: And I don't know where is your function `$('body').on("click", "button[name=likebtn]", function ()` in your js code if is in function document ready you have to call this function again if is outside of them  you haven't to do it

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already added class 'btn-primary' to your button. And u just need to add Class 'btn btn-mini likebtn' and to remove the class 'btn-primary'. Then just try the below one.

```
$(this).addClass('btn btn-mini likebtn').removeClass('btn-primary');
```

Comment: In fact, I just need to remove btn-primary

Comment: If u just need to remove the class 'btn-primary'. $(this).removeClass('btn-primary');